# Directory pointing to self /creating application with a built-in database

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection

I made a simple program with a database connection:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String

Dim ds As New DataSet 'holds table data
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter 'connection to database connectionobject
Dim sql As String

dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbSource = "Data Source = C:/JIMMY.mdb"

con.Open()

sql = "select * from TURNING"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "RECORDS")

con.Close()
```

Now I heard from someone that in order to make an application with a built in database, I should place the file inside the project.

> C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\myProject\JIMMY.MDB

How do I make the directory dynamic? So, wherever I place the published application, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it relative to the application, as explained in *[HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)*:

```
Dim path As String
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
dbSource = "Data Source = " + Path.Combine(path, "jimmy.mdb")
```

Comment: why is there a "file" at the beginning of the string? any tips how to remove it? also it seems like path.Concat was the right one

Comment: there was also this warning: Warning 1 Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.